# Message signature was incorrect error with OpenID

Tags: bug, login, data-explorer, openid

I just tried to login on Data Explorer using SE.

After entering my credentials, I have seen this error message:

[image: Message signature was incorrect error]

After pressing on the *Log in using Stack Exchange* button again, I was immediately logged in.